# How to fix docker-entrypoint.sh permission error

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have a dockerfile similar to this:

```
FROM centos:7

LABEL org.opencontainers.image.title="tig-slurm-cluster" \
      org.opencontainers.image.description="Slurm Docker cluster with TIG stack on CentOS 7" \
      org.label-schema.docker.cmd="docker-compose up -d" \

    

ARG SLURM_TAG=slurm-22-05-2-1
ARG GOSU_VERSION=1.11

RUN set -ex \
    && yum makecache fast \
    && yum -y update \
    && yum -y install epel-release \
    && yum -y install \
       wget \
       bzip2 \
       perl \
       gcc \
       gcc-c++\
       git \
       gnupg \
       #lua \
       #lua-devel \
       make \
       munge \
       munge-devel \
       python-devel \
       python-pip \
       python36 \
       python36-devel \
       python36-pip \
       mariadb-server \
       mariadb-devel \
       psmisc \
       bash-completion \
       vim-enhanced \
    && yum clean all \
    && rm -rf /var/cache/yum
    

#RUN pip install Cython nose && pip3.6 install Cython nose \
#    && pip3.6 install mysql-connector-python python-daemon


RUN set -ex \
    && wget -O /usr/local/bin/gosu "https://github.com/tianon/gosu/releases/download/$GOSU_VERSION/gosu-amd64" \
    && wget -O /usr/local/bin/gosu.asc "https://github.com/tianon/gosu/releases/download/$GOSU_VERSION/gosu-amd64.asc" \
    && export GNUPGHOME="$(mktemp -d)" \
    && gpg --batch --keyserver hkps://keys.openpgp.org --recv-keys B42F6819007F00F88E364FD4036A9C25BF357DD4 \
    && gpg --batch --verify /usr/local/bin/gosu.asc /usr/local/bin/gosu \
    && rm -rf "${GNUPGHOME}" /usr/local/bin/gosu.asc \
    && chmod +x /usr/local/bin/gosu \
    && gosu nobody true

RUN set -x \
    && git clone https://github.com/SchedMD/slurm.git \
    && pushd slurm \
    && git checkout tags/$SLURM_TAG \
    && ./configure --enable-debug --prefix=/usr --sysconfdir=/etc/slurm \
        --with-mysql_config=/usr/bin  --libdir=/usr/lib64 \
    && make install \
    && install -D -m644 etc/cgroup.conf.example /etc/slurm/cgroup.conf.example \
    && install -D -m644 etc/slurm.conf.example /etc/slurm/slurm.conf.example \
    && install -D -m644 etc/slurmdbd.conf.example /etc/slurm/slurmdbd.conf.example \
    && install -D -m644 contribs/slurm_completion_help/slurm_completion.sh /etc/profile.d/slurm_completion.sh \
    && popd \
   # && rm -rf slurm \
    && groupadd -r --gid=995 slurm \
    && useradd -r -g slurm --uid=995 slurm \
    && mkdir /etc/sysconfig/slurm \
        /var/spool/slurmd \
        /var/run/slurmd \
        /var/run/slurmdbd \
        /var/lib/slurmd \
        /var/log/slurm \
        /data \
    && touch /var/lib/slurmd/node_state \
        /var/lib/slurmd/front_end_state \
        /var/lib/slurmd/job_state \
        /var/lib/slurmd/resv_state \
        /var/lib/slurmd/trigger_state \
        /var/lib/slurmd/assoc_mgr_state \
        /var/lib/slurmd/assoc_usage \
        /var/lib/slurmd/qos_usage \
        /var/lib/slurmd/fed_mgr_state \
    && chown -R slurm:slurm /var/*/slurm* \
    && /sbin/create-munge-key \
    && pwd

ARG SUBMIT_VERSION=unknown




COPY slurm.conf /etc/slurm/slurm.conf
COPY slurmdbd.conf /etc/slurm/slurmdbd.conf

COPY docker-entrypoint.sh /usr/local/bin/docker-entrypoint.sh
RUN ["chmod", "+x", "/usr/local/bin/docker-entrypoint.sh"]
RUN ["ls", "-la", "/usr/local/bin/"]
ENTRYPOINT ["/usr/local/bin/docker-entrypoint.sh"]

CMD ["slurmdbd"]
```

With the following docker-compose.yml:

```
version: "0.1"

services:
  mysql:
    image: mysql
    hostname: mysql
    container_name: mysql
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: rootpassword
      MYSQL_DATABASE: slurm_acct_db
      MYSQL_USER: slurm
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: password
      MYSQL_ROOT_HOST: "%"
#      MYSQL_HOST: "%"
    ports:
      - '3306:3306'
    volumes:
      - var_lib_mysql:/var/lib/mysql

  slurmdbd:
    image: tig-slurm-cluster:22.05.2
    command: ["slurmdbd"]
    container_name: slurmdbd
    hostname: slurmdbd
    volumes:
      - etc_munge:/etc/munge
      - etc_slurm:/etc/slurm
      - var_log_slurm:/var/log/slurm
      - usr:/usr
    expose:
      - "6819"
    depends_on:
      - mysql

  slurmctld:
    image: tig-slurm-cluster:22.05.2
    command: ["slurmctld"]
    container_name: slurmctld
    hostname: slurmctld
    volumes:
      - etc_munge:/etc/munge
      - etc_slurm:/etc/slurm
      - slurm_jobdir:/home
      - var_log_slurm:/var/log/slurm
      - usr:/usr
    expose:
      - "6817"
    depends_on:
      - "slurmdbd"

  c1:
    image: tig-slurm-cluster:22.05.2
    command: ["slurmd"]
    hostname: c1
    container_name: c1
    volumes:
      - etc_munge:/etc/munge
      - etc_slurm:/etc/slurm
      - slurm_jobdir:/home/
      - var_log_slurm:/var/log/slurm
      - usr:/usr
    expose:
      - "6818"
    depends_on:
      - "slurmctld"

  c2:
    image: tig-slurm-cluster:22.05.2
    command: ["slurmd"]
    hostname: c2
    container_name: c2
    volumes:
      - etc_munge:/etc/munge
      - etc_slurm:/etc/slurm
      - slurm_jobdir:/home
      - var_log_slurm:/var/log/slurm
      - usr:/usr
    expose:
      - "6818"
    depends_on:
      - "slurmctld"

volumes:
  etc_munge:
  etc_slurm:
  slurm_jobdir:
  var_lib_mysql:
  var_log_slurm:
  usr:
```

When I build and try to run `docker-compose up -d` it only manages to start the mysql container. The others dont start.

If I try to start them in the docker gui the error at the top is:

```
Error invoking remote method 'docker-start-container': Error: (HTTP code 400) unexpected - failed to create task for container: failed to create shim task: OCI runtime create failed: runc create failed: unable to start container process: exec: "/usr/local/bin/docker-entrypoint.sh": permission denied: unknown
```

Although in the build I check that the docker-entrypoint.sh has been copied over and that it is executable:

```
#14 [10/10] RUN ["ls", "-la", "/usr/local/bin/"]
#14 0.160 total 2264
#14 0.160 drwxr-xr-x 1 root root    4096 Jun 21 15:41 .
#14 0.160 drwxr-xr-x 1 root root    4096 Nov 13  2020 ..
#14 0.160 -rwxr-xr-x 1 root root    1588 Jun 21 14:24 docker-entrypoint.sh
#14 0.160 -rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 2294944 Dec  7  2021 gosu
```

Can anyone spot the issue here?

Comment: It's not part of your problem, but why are you using `version: "0.1"`?

Comment: W/r/t your problem, what if you instead set `ENTRYPOINT ["bash", "/usr/local/bin/docker-entrypoint.sh"]`? Does that work, or do you continue to experience an error?

Comment: The volume mounts that replace all of `/usr` with a shared volume will cause massive problems. As a specific point thing, whatever's in `/usr/local/bin` in the volume will hide the image's `/usr/local`, but this also applies to system binaries in `/usr/bin`, shared libraries in `/usr/lib`, and so on.  Does deleting the `usr` volume entirely help?

Comment: @larsks suggestion didnt help, but David's did a bit. I deleted the `/usr` volume and now the containers seem to start - bar one (though the others depend on it, so maybe if it where to start they would also have issues). The logs for the failing one `slurmdbd` gets the error 
`
2023-06-21 20:31:20 ---> Starting the MUNGE Authentication service (munged) ...
2023-06-21 20:31:20 ---> Starting the Slurm Database Daemon (slurmdbd) ...
2023-06-21 20:31:20 /usr/local/bin/docker-entrypoint.sh: line 12: /etc/slurm/slurmdbd.conf: No such file or directory
`
But that file exists...